# feynmp-auto and --output-directory=build not possible?

Tags: options, feynmp-auto

I really like the automisation by `feynmp-auto`, but I also want to keep my working directory clean, especially in git repos.

So I always use `--output-directory=build` when compiling documents. However it seems that `feynmp-auto` is not able to work with this option.

#### Case I: \begin{fmffile}{example}

- metapost does not find the file because it is created in build/ but it searches in the base directory

#### Case II \begin{fmffile}{example}

- metapost would find the file, but no latex throws an error because it tries to save the mp file in build/build,  which naturally does not exist.

Is there any workaround, so that I can use both feynmp-auto and --output-directory=build?

Minimal example which compiles if used without the output directory option:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\unitlength=1mm

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{example}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not supported, at the moment. I can think to add it.

Comment: that would be great ;)

Comment: I'm afraid supporting this would introduce operating system dependencies. We have to run `mpost` inside the output directory and I'm not sure whether the Windows command shell accepts a syntax such as `cd somedir;mpost file`. In any case this needs more patching to `feynmp` and I'm a bit reluctant.

Comment: so, as long as i'm on a linux system i could add an option, e.g. `working-directory`, and change the lines with `\immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}%` to an if/else with `\immediate\write18{cd \theoutputdirectory; mpost \thefmffile}%` if the option is provided?

Comment: That seems to somehow work, but then the MPS file is not found; but I don't think it's possible to make it work on every system, so don't expect a change. I'm not keen on doing something that requires `\ifwindows`.

Comment: @egreg Has there been any change to this since the original post was made?

Comment: If you are trying to make feynman graphs in 2021, have a look at tikz-feynman instead of feynmp